# Function for calculating variance of aspect ratio of rectangles

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, geometry

How to implement a function that evaluates the variance of the aspect ratio of two given rectangles

The attached picture has some rectangles.

To me as a person it seems that the difference in aspect ratio between rectangle `B` and rectangle `C` is the same as the variance between rectangle `C` and rectangle `D`, but numerically the difference between `B` and `C` is `0.34` while the difference between `C` and `D` is `0.5`.

How can one know in a programming and mathematical way that rectangle `B` is similar to rectangle C and equally rectangle `D` is similar to rectangle `C`?

It can also be said that rectangle `A` is similar to rectangle `B` in the same way that rectangle `D` is similar to rectangle `E`, because the variance of their aspect ratio is the same, But numerically it does not work out, because the difference between `A` and `B` is `0.16`, and the difference between `D` and `E` is `0.5`.

[image]

This is the code I was trying to write, there are two approaches here, that I knew how to start but I do not know how to continue to implement them.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle A, B, C, D, E;
              
        // First approach
        double maxDiff = ???;
        Console.WriteLine(IsSimilar(B, C, maxDiff)); // True

        // Second approach
        Console.WriteLine(GetDifference(B, C) == GetDifference(C, D)); // True
    }

    // -------------- First approach --------------
    public static bool IsSimilar(Rectangle rectangle1, Rectangle rectangle2, double maxDiff)
    {
        var score1 = GetRatioScore(rectangle1);
        var score2 = GetRatioScore(rectangle2);
        return Math.Abs(score1 - score2) <= maxDiff;
    }

    private static double GetRatioScore(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        ...
        return ...
    }

    // -------------- Second approach --------------
    public static double GetDifference(Rectangle rectangle1, Rectangle rectangle2)
    {
        var ratio1 = rectangle1.Width / rectangle1.Height;
        var ratio2 = rectangle2.Width / rectangle2.Height;
        ...
        return ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Note that the direction of the rectangle is involved in the calculation, so that rectangle `A` and rectangle `E` are completely different and not equal in their aspect ratio.

Comment: You could try computing the ratio of the ratios rather than the difference of them. For example ratio(C)/ratio(B) ~ 1.5 = ratio(D)/ratio(C)

Comment: You could take `Math.Abs(Math.Log(ratio))` as a measure. Or just invert a ratio when it is less than `1.0`.

Comment: I think what you want is normalized ratio. That means longer side / shorter side, for example... which is the same as Clemens suggestion to invert ratio if < 1

Comment: @Clemens The calculation: `Math.Abs(Math.Log(ratio))` does not work well, because rectangle `B` and rectangle `D` get the same result `0.405` supposedly are the same as their aspect ratio, which is obviously not true.

Comment: It obviously returns a measure for the "normalized" aspect ratio, e.g. the one you get when you first transform all "portrait" rectangles to "landscape". That is exactly what you were asking for. Do not confuse that measure with the actual aspect ratio, which can still be less or greater than 1. It is just meant to be used for the comparison of two rectanges. Did you not want to get something that is equal for B and D?

Comment: @Clemens I edited my question about an hour ago, and the direction of the rectangle is involved in the calculation, so that `B` and `D` cannot be equal, and normalizing the ratio  leads to an incorrect result.

Comment: "*numerically the difference between B and C is 0.34 while the difference between C and D is 0.5*" - try the same with the measure I am proposing. You will find out that `M(C)-M(B)` equals `M(C)-M(D)`. That is what you call "*equally similar*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a number that describes the aspect ratio, where:

1. Width and height symmetrically, so that it if you switch width for height you get the same number with opposite sign.  Squares have to be zero
2. The number doesn't change if you multiply width and height by the same constant

You can just make up ways.  Let F be any odd monotonically increasing functions.  Then:

Any F(w/sqrt(w * h)) - F(h/sqrt(w * h)) works

Any F(log(w) - log(h)) works

I think my favorite is just the difference between width and height for a rectangle of unit area: (w-h)/sqrt(w * h).

(w/h) - (h/w) also works and is kinda similar in magnitude to the normal aspect ratio.

Comment: Thank you so much, math is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Given a rectangle with sides `a` and `b`, simply compute the ratio as:

```
var ratio = a > b ? b/a : a/b;
```

The orientation of the rectangle doesn't seem to be involved in the ratio you need so you have to come up with an orientation agnostic ratio; the easiest way is to consistently divide the short side by the long side (or the opposite, consistency is the key).

Comment: Thank you, but the direction of the rectangle is involved in the calculation, so that rectangle A and rectangle E are completely different.